# Mysql table isn't sorted correctly after inserting records with Prisma

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, next.js, prisma

I am using Prisma in a Next.js project with a MySQL database. If I create a new record, it doesn't get inserted at the last line of my table. [I inserted the data in the order 1,2,3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Slami.png)). Somehow 3 gets inserted in the middle of the table instead of the last row.

```
//schema.prisma
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model tasks {
  id        String  @id @db.VarChar(255)
  title     String  @db.VarChar(255)
  text      String? @db.Text
  tags      String? @db.VarChar(255)
  createdBy String  @db.VarChar(255)
  time      String  @db.VarChar(255)
  date      String  @db.VarChar(255)
  completed Int     @db.TinyInt
}
```

```
//route.ts
import { prisma } from "@/lib/prisma"

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const { id, title, text, tags, completed, createdBy, time, date } =
    await req.json()

  const response = await prisma.tasks.create({
    data: {
      id: id,
      title: title,
      text: text,
      tags: tags,
      completed: completed,
      createdBy: createdBy,
      time: time,
      date: date,
    },
  })

  return new Response(JSON.stringify(response))
}
```

I am expecting, that the data gets inserted in the right order (1,2,3) instead of (1, 3, 2). I've tried to insert the record via MySQL console and the table is sorted in the right order, such as expected. That's why the problem seems to has to do with Prisma.

Comment: Table order is not important, rather you should specify sorting in your query to retrieve records

Comment: So you would recommend me to specify sorting in my query, where I retrieve the records by a property such as data or time? But isn't there a way to sort the table automatically with prisma by the latest added record?